# openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3

Tags: openssl, debian, libssl

it doesn't matter what I type in combination with 'openssl', I always get the following error message:

```
'openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

I have no idea how to fix that issue after reading many questions asked in this and in other forums.

Comment: Looks similar at your problem https://serverfault.com/questions/818445/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libcrypto-so-1-1

Comment: Yes I have seen this before. But nevertheless looking at it twice helped me and I fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it that time only by creating a symlink and rebuilding the ldconfig cache.

```
ln -s libssl.so.3 libssl.so
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: would be helpful if you can tell us the fully qualified paths to the .sos in your `ln` command;

for me it was enough to just execute `sudo ldconfig` after compiling and installing openssl

Comment: I did this: # ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.3 and # ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (and then of course rebuild the cache with ldconfig)

Answer (score 39):

```
ldconfig /usr/local/lib64/
```

with compilation from sourecs:

```
./Configure
make
make install
ldconfig /usr/local/lib64/
```

You could add `/usr/local/lib64/` path to your linker parmanently. In some linux distros it isn't added. Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334365/how-to-add-a-directory-to-linker-command-line-in-linux)

Comment: Working solution, works perfect. Thank you Eugene!
Now, time to read into ldconfig, as I only mildy know what it does.

Comment: somehow it's not persistent for me. The error came again after reboot or logout

Comment: @Ragtime, meybe you should try to add /usr/local/lib64/ to your linker permanently? https://askubuntu.com/questions/334365/how-to-add-a-directory-to-linker-command-line-in-linux

Comment: Thanks so much! I did
`echo "/usr/local/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf`
after your command and it's now working perfectly!

Comment: Could you share any info on what this answer actually does?

Comment: @jschmitter you just need to read aswer attentively.

Comment: @EugeneLopatkin I have, many times :) There's a fair bit of context that would be helpful for beginners like myself, for example: 1) What is ldconfig? 2) Why are these particular sources necessary in order to solve the original issue? 3) how does one determine when this of solution is appropriate for a given error? You could expect readers to do their own research, but the technical documentation on this point is a bit overwhelming. Since people are often eager to share knowledge on SO, I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 16):

I compiled openssl from github: https://github.com/openssl/openssl.
Examining the Makefile generated (by `./config`) the default install directory is `/usr/local/lib64`.

However, on RHEL, this directory is not in the load library path.  The following worked for me on RHEL 7.9:

Edit ld.conf file to add a line containing /usr/local/lib64 :

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/lib.conf
/usr/local/lib64
```

Sometimes, openssl is installed at /usr/local/ssl, and a file like /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf is created. The path to libraries can be added here:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf
/usr/local/ssl/lib64
```

After adding the path to the file, update the library paths

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Sanity check

```
$ openssl version
Output: OpenSSL 3.0.0-alpha11 28 jan 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.0-alpha11 28 jan 2021)
```

Comment: on ubuntu i had to adjust the path in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl-3.0.2.conf

Comment: Thanks I added my installation path and it worked straightaway

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue after installing Openssl 3.0. I resolved the issue by copying the files `libcrypto.so.3`, `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.so.3` from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/lib`.
After copying these files, you need to create some symbolic links.

```
ln -s libcrypto.so.3 libcrypto.so
ln -s libssl.so.3 libssl.so
```

Now rebuild the ldconfig cache:

`sudo ldconfig`

Comment: This is dangerous advice, and should not be followed. Files in `/usr/lib` should be managed by your operating system's package manager -- overwriting them will leave your system in an inconsistent state.

Comment: It is a dirty hack, but it worked on my Ubuntu 16. I compiled and installed the current openssl and curl (which uses openssl). I think when building Openssl there is an option you can pass to configure for the install path, to usr/lib in this case.

Comment: I had a similar error installing openssl from stratch: openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

This trick worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was related to Python 3.8 install on SLES 12.1. Pip install failed due to OpenSSL error.

Then I cloned the openssl repository and built it from source.

`git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git`

`./Configure`
`make`
`make install`

Finally `ldconfig` is important and needed.

Then `openssl version -a` should show response without error. At least openssl 1.1 is needed to build Python 3.5+.

After this exercise the Python 3.8.5 build from the source was successful.

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS 7, for OpenSSL 3.0.0, this did the job for me

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.3 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.3 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3
```

No system restart or ldcache config rebuild required.

Answer (score 2):

Compile and run your code using `sudo`. It will work.

If it doesn't work then follow the below steps

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

Answer (score 2):

I initially had this issue on Fedora 22 (fc22.x86_64) (yes....old server). I was upgrading from an old version of OpenSSL (1.0.2) to OpenSSL 3.0.1. The following solution worked for me installing from the downloaded source openssl-3.0.1.tar.gz. I firstly uninstalled my previous version of OpenSSL which had not been installed from source, but rather DNF.

Uninstall previous version with DNF (OpenSSL 1.0.2)

dnf remove openssl openssl-devel

```
Install OpenSSL 3.0.1

$ cd /usr/src

$ tar zxvf openssl-3.0.1.tar.gz

$ cd /usr/src/openssl-3.0.1/

$ ./config

$ make

$ make install

$ ldconfig /usr/local/lib64/

$ openssl version

OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021)
```

Answer (score 2):

Careful because if you upgrade on Manjaro you might destroy your system - Pacman and even Sudo rely on openssl-1.1, so you want to have the latest and the older both installed at the same time or you'll need to mount from a boot and repair.

Answer (score 1):

After installing **openssl-3.0.0** i noticed that `libssl.so.3` and `libcrypto.so.3` files were located in `/usr/local/ssl/lib64`.

This worked for me :

- I edited the **openssl-X.y.z.conf** file located in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and changed `/usr/local/ssl/lib` to **/usr/local/ssl/lib64**
- I reloaded using **ldconfig**

Started runing these tow commands :

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

sudo vim openssl-Z.y.z.config
```

Changed the file, saved it and exited from vim editor.

Ran

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

I had output like :

```
#...
libssl3.so -> libssl3.so
#...
```

And make verification again

```
openssl version
```

My output:

```
OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.0 7 sep 2021)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by some mamba/conda transaction, which has upgraded openssl to 3.0, version not present on the computer I did not have root to. When it is your situation calm down and simply downgrade

```
mamba install openssl=1.1.1t
```

or

```
conda install openssl=1.1.1t
```

Answer (score 1):

For RedHat 7.9 after installing OpenSSL 3.1.0, I was able to see the version as root but not as regular user, so I sent this commands that finally helped me

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.3 /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.3 /usr/lib
$ sudo ldconfig
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023)
```

finally problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libssl.so.1.0.2/libssl.so.1.0.2 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2
ln -s /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.2/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the similar issue with the **`alpine`** based images upon running the upgrade command `apk --no-cache -U -a upgrade`

So, had to adjust the Dockerfile in the following way:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN apk add --update openssl \
    && apk --no-cache -U -a upgrade

. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by running:
**apt install libffi7**

Answer (score -1):

This solution [from kingaj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66049182/17678609) (pasted below), also works for **Ubuntu 20.04**.  I tested it and it worked perfectly:

"...I compiled openssl from github: https://github.com/openssl/openssl. Examining the Makefile generated (by ./config) the default install directory is /usr/local/lib64.

However, on RHEL, this directory is not in the load library path. The following worked for me on RHEL 7.9:..."

```
$ sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/lib.conf

# edit ld.conf file 
# add a line containing `/usr/local/lib64`
$ sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/lib.conf

# update the library paths
$ sudo ldconfig

# sanity check
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.0-alpha11 28 jan 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.0-alpha11 28 jan 2021)
```