# How to fix an error `libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: linux, archlinux, barrier, libcrypto

### Premise

I want to share a single keyboard between two computers(ArchLinux and Windows), and there are some options to realize it on.

I choiced an option using Barrier.

### Expect

Following steps bellow on a ArchLinux machine and verify there are no error:

Installing barrier : `$ sudo pacman -S barrier`

Using barrier : `$ barrier`

### Actual

I got error at the step using barrier.

The error message is : `barrier: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

### Question

How to fix "No such file or directory" about libcrypto.so.3?

### Additional information

#### Commands output

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/barrier | grep libcrypto
        libcrypto.so.3 => not found
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fcf0f000000)
```

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep libcrypto
        libcrypto.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
        libcrypto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so
```

### Tried things

1. Executed `sudo barrier`, nothing new.
2. Searched Barrier issues on github, and I obtained no result about the problem not found `libcrypto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to fix

At the [issue](https://github.com/koijigen/question-and-answer/issues/1) in my Github repository , I knew that `libcrypto` is a library that is included the package `openssl` .

And I did reinstalling `openssl`, installing `openssl-1.1` and executing command `$ barrier`, no error, Barrier was launched.

### Cause of error

Probablly, The error was occured by I had not the library `libcrypto.so.3`in my machine. So, when I reinstalliing `openssl` (i.e. update by `pacman -Sy openssl`), the library is placed in `/usr/lib`, and the error had dissapeared.

### References

1. [OpenSSL's issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/19497#issuecomment-1304659369)
2. [StackOverflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s#answer-28460293)

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54124906/4062818)

Sometimes might be helpful just to downgrade python installed openssl by e.g.

```
mamba install openssl=1.1.1t
```